# La vraie définition de « Sainte nitouche »

Tags: usage, sens, étymologie

En écoutant une musique, je me suis demandé ce que voulait vraiment dire *Sainte nitouche*. Est-ce une femme ou un homme qui cachent des choses et se donnent un air innocent ? Ou est-ce quelqu'un de vraiment innocent et modeste ?

Quelle est l’étymologie de ce mot ? Quel genre de personne utilisait ce mot et dans quelle situation ? Y a-t-il des exemples historiques et des exemples récents ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comme d'habitude, le sens de quelque chose c'est ce qu'on pense que ça veut dire, donc ce que ça veut dire vraiment c'est ce que tes interlocuteurs comprennent. Pour les références historiques et l'étymologie le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/) a la réponse suivante

> *Fam., péj.* **Jeune fille ou femme qui joue à la prude, qui prend hypocritement des airs offensés**. *Quand on fait la sainte-nitouche, comme vous, on devrait au moins, après avoir carotté des personnes bienfaisantes, ne pas les appeler vieilles tourtes!* (Huysmans, Sœurs Vatard, 1879, p. 328). *Il ne se moque jamais des choses religieuses comme font certaines saintes nitouches* (Montherl., Ville dont prince, 1951, I, 3, p. 870).
>   […] **Étymol. et Hist.** 1534 interj. *Saincte Nytouche!* (Rabelais, Gargantua, XXV, 129, éd. R. Calder, p. 173); 1545 subst. u*ne sainte nytouche*(Lemaçon, Trad. de Boccace, 5ejourn., X ds Gdf. Compl.). Du fém. de *saint* et de *nitouche* mot plais. formé de *n[e]*, *y* et *touche*, forme verbale de *toucher*, littéral. « qui n'y touche pas, qui n'a pas l'air d'y toucher »<sup>[TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sainte+nitouche)</sup>